# Thread-pool friendly approach to Sleep?

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, httpmodule

I want to insert a sleep (aka throttle, delay, tarpit, dwell) in an ASP.net application (imagine something like failed logon attempt escalating delay).

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Int32 sleepyTime = GetSleepyTime(Request);

    if (sleepyTime > 0)
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(sleepyTime);


    //...Continue normal processing
}
```

I want all remaining processing to continue as normal; i just want the user agent to suffer.

The problem is that ASP.net uses a ThreadPool to handle requests. If i were to `Sleep` for 5, 10, 30 seconds, i would be eating up a valuable limited resource.

I assume it needs to be something like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Int32 sleepyTime = GetSleepyTime(Request);

    if (sleepyTime > 0)
       ABetterKindOfSleep(sleepyTime);

    //...Continue normal processing
}

private void ABetterKindOfSleep(int milliseconds)
{
   await SleepAsync(milliseconds);
}

private async void SleepAsync(int milliseconds)
{
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(milliseconds);
}
```

But never having written any async/await code, and not understanding the logic behind where the `async` and `await` go, or why, or even if it can be used to run async code: i don't know if it can be used to run async code.

### Bonus Reading

- [Does Thread.Sleep affect the ThreadPool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23657709/does-thread-sleep-affect-the-threadpool)
- [Sleeping in a pooled C# thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305814/sleeping-in-a-pooled-c-sharp-thread)
- [How to delay / throttle login attempts in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761313/how-to-delay-throttle-login-attempts-in-asp-net)
- [Asynchronous Thread.Sleep()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15924221/asynchronous-thread-sleep)

Comment: Your tag indicates that you are using .NET 2.0. How ever the `async`/`await` pattern is something that came along with .NET 4.0. Did you select the wrong tag or was this intentional?

Comment: @Nitram The solution that works on older web-sites (e.g. if i asked this question in 2005) is, obviously, better. Especially since i have some code that is locked in 2.0. But if .NET 2 didn't support thread pools, i'll have to accept there's no way to throttle. But i'll take what i can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy enough.

First you create an `IHttpModule` class:

```
class TarpitHttpModule : IHttpModule
{
}
```

And then you let IIS know about this module by registering it in `web.config`:

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
         <add name="Tarpit" type="TarpitHttpModule"/>
```

If you are Cassini, add it to:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <httpModules>
         <add name="Tarpit" type="TarpitHttpModule"/>
```

Whenever an http request comes in, IIS will call your `.Init` method. This is where you will register your async event handler using:

- **[Application.AddOnBeginRequestAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpapplication.addonbeginrequestasync?view=netframework-4.8)**: Adds the specified [`BeginRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpapplication.beginrequest?view=netframework-4.8) event to the collection of asynchronous [`BeginRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpapplication.beginrequest?view=netframework-4.8) event handlers for the current request.

**Code:**

```
public void Init(HttpApplication application)
{
    //This is the synchronous event handler; which we don't want
    //application.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(this.Application_BeginRequest);

    //EventHandlerTaskAsyncHelper requires .NET 4.5
    //https://brockallen.com/2013/07/27/implementing-async-http-modules-in-asp-net-using-tpls-task-api/ 
    //  Archive: http://archive.is/Cdvle
    //
    //Normally you'd have to write a pair of methods:
    //    application.AddOnBeginRequestAsync(OnBegin, OnEnd);
    //
    //and then we'd have to write an OnBegin which returns IAsyncResult, and then OnEnd which takes the IAsyncResult.
    //The modern way is to use Tasks, and use the IAsyncResult that a Task **is**.
    //Fortunately the .NET team wrote a handy class that wraps up the boilerplate catching faults, etc,
    //and created the EventHandlerTaskAsyncHelper class

    var beginTaskHelper = new EventHandlerTaskAsyncHelper(BeginRequestAsync);
    application.AddOnBeginRequestAsync(beginTaskHelper.BeginEventHandler, beginTaskHelper.EndEventHandler);
}
```

So now we have to supply the **BeginRequestAsync** asynchronous handler:

```
async Task BeginRequestAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var application = (HttpApplication)sender;
    var context = application.Context;

    // In reality i would use the context.Request to come up with a unique key 
    // for this user agent e.g. 
    String key = SHA256(UserHostAddress+UserAgent+AcceptTypes+UserLanguages).ToBase64();
    // And use that as a cache key store information about this user agent
    Object tarpitInfo = context.Cache.Get(agentIdentity);
    if (ti == null)
        return;

    // But in this SO demo, i'm just going to unconditionally sleep
    Boolean waitPerformed = await PerformDelay(context, tarpitInfo);
    if (waitPerformed)
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 429;
        context.Response.StatusDescription = "Too Many Requests";
        context.Response.End();
        return;
    }
}
```

And then the work of sleeping:

```
async Task<Boolean> PerformDelay(HttpContext context, TarInfo ti)
{
    int delayMs = 3000;
    Task delay = Task.Delay(delayMs);
    await delay;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What is the overhead of having lots of requests awaiting? It's not blocking a thread but it must use some memory. Couldn't it hit the default max concurrent request limit quite easily? I think it's 5000 requests.

Answer (score 1):

The `async` equivalent of `Thread.Sleep` is `await Task.Delay`:

```
if (sleepyTime > 0)
  await Task.Delay(sleepyTime);
```

Note that this must be used in the context of an `async` method, and there are limitations (particularly on WebForms) on where `async` can be used. For more information, see my [article on `async` ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx) and the [official tutorial on `async` WebForms](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45).

Answer (score 0):

I also want to tarpit bot traffic attacking login endpoints, I'm worried that if I simply await that I will hit the max concurrent requests or run out of memory. I have yet to find a low overhead way of doing this with Windows and Asp.Net.

I like the way it is [done here](https://www.secureworks.com/research/ddos), where it changes the behaviour of the TCP/IP stack to shrink the window size and not ACK subsequent packets which makes the remote exponentially back off and only send a tiny amount of data.

I will likely add a few Linux VMs running HAProxy in-front to take advantage of its [DDOS capabilities](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/application-layer-ddos-attack-protection-with-haproxy/)